# Determine if count of related model > 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a model called `Stem`. I need a 'thumbs up' feature, so I have created a second model called `Thumb`, which consists of `stem_id` and `user_id`.

I'm also using the restful authentication plugin for user credentials.

I have the 'thumbs up' button working, which adds a row to the `thumbs` table fine, but I'd like to be able to check if the currently logged in user has already given a thumbs up to this particular stem.

I tried adding this to the `Stem` model:

```
def thumbed
    Thumb.count_by_sql ["SELECT COUNT(*) FROM thumbs WHERE user_id = ? AND stem_id = ?", current_user.id, self.id ]
end
```

The problem here is that the `stem` model has no access to the `current_user` variable the the controllers have.

Is there a way I can get access to this property, or alternatively, is there another way I could go about checking this? I was hoping to get this as a property in the model because the stems are passed over to a Flex app using RubyAMF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your controller knows the current_user, and your `Stem` model probably shouldn't. You can, however clean up your code and avoid hard-wiring SQL with a `named_scope` and pass the user into that.

```
#thumb.rb
named_scope :for_user_id, lambda {|id| {:conditions => {:user_id => id}}}

#stem.rb
def thumbed_by_user(user)
  self.thumbs.for_user_id(user.id).count > 0
end


# some controller
stem = some_method_that_gets_a_stem
is_already_thumbed = stem.thumbed_by_user(current_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass the current user to `thumbed`? Where are you calling it from?

BTW, you could try to simplify all of this using associations. I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you have the following...

```
class Stem
  has_many :thumbs
end

class User
  has_many :thumbs
end

class Thumb
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :stem
end
```

Then you can use find though associations to get at your thumbs without resorting to direct SQL. Check out this RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/3-find-through-association

Comment: Yeah, I do have associations like those set up, I could change from the sql to something else, provided I have the current user's id.

I can't use any arguments on thumbed because I am hoping my Flex app will read it as a property when I pass the data over through RubyAMF

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I can't help much because I have never used RubyAMF. Perhaps you can call an action in your thumbs_controller from your flex app, and that can check the user_id? I think the fundamental issue here is that you're trying to do something in the model layer when it might belong in the controller. And from what I can see, RubyAMF is designed to plug into the controller layer.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll just need to add a couple more steps into the process and put it in the controller

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working for me first was something like this:

I added these methods to my stem model:

```
def thumbed_by? usr_id
  Thumb.count(:conditions => {:user_id => usr_id, :stem_id => self.id}) > 0
end

def owned_by? usr_id
  self.id == usr_id
end
```

I also added this:

```
attr_accessor :thumbed, owned
```

Then in my show action where these were needed, I added the following lines:

```
@stem.thumbed = @stem.thumbed_by? current_user.id
@stem.owned = @stem.owned_by? current_user.id
```

This works exactly how I would like (the Flex app is already interpreting it as properly), but is there a way I could shorten this?